# What is it called when someone researches the manufacturing costs of a company to determine their profit level?

Tags: investing

I am interested of learning how to research (estimate) manufacturing costs of various companies. This is partially for the sake of determining their expenses.

Is there a name for this kind of evaluation or analysis? I am asking so that I search for books that discuss how this can be done.

Comment: this is on topic because fundamental analysis is related to personal finance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at the production cost wouldn't be anywhere near enough, but I think you are looking at "fundamental analysis". With fundamental analysis you try to estimate the actual value of a company, compare it to share prices, and buy shares where the fundamental value is higher than the share price, assuming that the market will eventually figure out that the shares are worth more, and then the share price goes up. With "technical analysis" you don't care what the company is worth, you just look at how the share prices has moved in the past and predict future share prices from that.